# Email reminder frequency to complete a task

Tags: email

I need some insight and data on the appropriate frequency of email reminders to a user to complete a specific task they have not submitted. The system will delete their information automatically after 30 days of inactivity, but we need to send them reminders to complete and submit their information and inform them that it will be deleted if they do not act.

As far as I am aware, the user cannot unsubscribe from this list because it's a business requirement to remind them to complete their information or it will be deleted, nor will they have the option to choose to receive less email. The only times we email them are confirmation emails and reminder emails.

Here are my questions related to this -

1. How many emails would be appropriate in this situation and why?
2. Is it necessary to inform them we when have deleted their information, though previous email(s) would notify them of impending deletion, and
   prompt them to start again with a link to our site in that email?

Comment: A few queries..1. What kind of information does the user have to enter? 2. By subscribing what information is expected to be sent and in what modes? 3. In future can the user unsubscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the specific business sector and whether you're a B2B or B2C company I'd suggest an email after 14 days, then on day 21, then on the final day. You don't want the user to be bombarded with emails but you do need to give them sufficient notice. You would ideally want different email subjects (at least) which say what's happening, and make clear that the user's details will be deleted on a specific date. This should work for B2B

You don't need to tell them that you *have* deleted their details, as you've given them sufficient notice.

RE: Unsubscribing, you might need to check the legalities of that as it might be seen as a marketing email.

In the UK every marketing email;

> must give the person the ability to opt out of (or 'unsubscribe from' further emails ([OFCOM](https://www.gov.uk/marketing-advertising-law/direct-marketing)),

And in the US I think the CAN-SPAM Act (2003) says a:

> visible and operable unsubscribe mechanism is present in all emails ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN-SPAM_Act_of_2003)).

It is worth checking with the client as they'll be deemed responsible if they're reported and the relevant authority deems they've broken communications legislation.